# Create Version failed. Bad model detected with error: Model requires more memory than allowed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-ml

Two days ago I was able to upload multiple ML models (w/ custom prediction routine) without any issues.

Last night, I started receiving prediction response errors: "Prediction server is out of memory, possibly because model size is too big."

I tried to upload the exact same model and custom prediction routine today and am now receiving the error "Create Version failed. Bad model detected with error: Model requires more memory than allowed. Please try to decrease the model size and re-deploy. If you continue to have error, please contact Cloud ML."

Did something change that I am not aware of?

Comment: What's the size of model?

Comment: 213mb or so. Definitely less than 250mb

Comment: It may be safe to open a case with Google Cloud to make sure no Infrastructure changes are happening

Comment: I submitted a bug, but nothing. And I thought Google cares about their Cloud customers https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142580717

Comment: Hi Eric - Thanks for reporting the issue. It's very important for us to solve your problem with Cloud ML and we're looking into it. Let me get back to you.

Comment: Eric, I am looking into this. can you please send your project details to us at cloudml-feedback@google.com. We would like to look further into this.

Comment: Thanks but I already decided to go with another solution

Comment: @Bhupesh I am currently experiencing this issue with a pre-trained BERT model.  The model directory is slightly over 400mb, so I can see where I would be close, but I am unsure what would be causing me to go over the limit.  I would love to know where I could get some more information. Thanks.

Comment: @Bhupesh I have just quantized the model down to under 200mbs, but I still get the same error.  I am afraid that I don't know where to turn next...

Answer (score 1):

This took me more than a day of work to solve... Unfortunately.

Check your project setup.py. I discovered that if it has tensorflow on it the deploy process fails before any line of my prediction script is ran. I removed it and it worked.

You don't need tensorflow to be installed as it is already in the runtime. My guess is that memory allocated by the setup.py script with tensorflow to be too great and then the deploy process fails as a result.

The error message is completely misleading and should be patched.

From this:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name="my-project",
      version='0.0.1',
      scripts=['project/predict/predictor.py'],
      install_requires=[
          'pika==0.12.0',
          'unidecode==1.1.0',
          'tensorflow'
      ])
```

To this:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name="my-project",
      version='0.0.1',
      scripts=['project/predict/predictor.py'],
      install_requires=[
          'pika==0.12.0',
          'unidecode==1.1.0',
      ])
```

Answer (score 0):

I received a blazing fast response from cloudml-feedback@google.com about this issue. I was told to include pytorch from http://storage.googleapis.com/cloud-ai-pytorch/readme.txt.  This seems to have worked, but I am still having this problem with the transformers library.  I will update if I figure out how to include the transformers library in my model without an error.

Edit: I used `pip wheel transformers` to get the whl, but I see that it creates one for all of the dependencies too. Do I have to bundle all of these together, or can I just provide the transformers.whl?  Anyways, I am still getting the same error...

Comment: Hi, did you manage to resolve this issue? I am also getting the same error with transformers. How did you deploy your model with ai-platform? Thanks

Comment: Hi, I did get this to work at the time, but I am trying to put a PyTorch model up again and am running into issues.  I will let you know if I figure anything out.  If you ended up getting it to work I would love to have a chat.  Thanks.